# Django 3.1: Prepopulate a foreign key fiels using CreateView

Tags: django, django-views, foreign-keys

There are many answers concerning this topic. None of them which I read, helped me to find a way out.

*Situation:* I've a contact model and I wish to assign an email address. They reside in a table with a foreign key.

Now, I'd like to add a button: "add e-mail" which opens a form. As I am in the detail view of the contact, I'd like to hand the id over into the form to either pre- or post-populate the email object (fk to contact) with the contact pk.

The easiest way would from my point of view be to just add the pk to the url and use it in "form_valid".

The view:

```
class EmailCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = EmailAddress
fields = ('scope', 'email',)  # 'contact',
template_name = 'contacts/contact_form.html'
# initial = {'email': 'test'}

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.create_by = self.request.user.username
    form.instance.update_by = self.request.user.username
    # form.instance.contact = Contact.objects.get(self.kwargs['contact_pk']) <- not working
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

The urlpattern:

```
 path('email/add/', EmailCreateView.as_view(), name='add_email'),
```

The model:

```
class EmailAddress(CommonInfo):
scope = models.CharField('Bereich', max_length=2, choices=SCOPE_TYPES)
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, verbose_name='Kontakt', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
email = models.EmailField('E-Mail')

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.email)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('contacts:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.contact_id})
```

I really have no idea what I'm missing. As this is a standard case in DB development, it ought to be easy. I'm almost certain that I've overlooked something simple. But whenever I try to pass a url parameter over, I run into a **NoReverseMatch** error.

Comment: In your url path, there is no `contact_pk`.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. Whenever I change my url to:
`<a href="{% url 'contacts:add_email' contact_pk=contact.id %}">some_link</a>`
I have the mentioned NoReverseMatch error.

Comment: I'm ashamed but I have to admit that it was just a stupid error in my template: As I had another widget used earlier, and it was still in the template, it was correctly complaining since I didn't change the second...
However, thank you for your help. This was my first post after years of using stackoverflow and I promise to look better next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.create_by = self.request.user.username
        self.object.update_by = self.request.user.username
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```